# Call modal inside ascx from different ascx page on span click

Tags: javascript, c#, ascx

I have a modal inside page1.ascx which needs to be called on span click from page2.ascx. I am unable to make it work. Please help.

Page2.ascx

```html
  <ul class="nav metismenu" id="side-menu">          
            <li id="nav_callback" runat="server">
                <a><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> <span class="nav-label spmodal" onclick="open_request_callback()">Request Callback</span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Page2.ascx (JS function)

```
   function open_request_callback() {
            $get("<%=btn_open_request_callback.ClientID %>").click();
        }
```

Page2.ascx (asp:Button click):

```
<div class="hidden">   
    <asp:Button ID="btn_open_request_callback" runat="server" OnClick="btn_open_request_callback_Click" />   
</div>

<telerik:RadAjaxManagerProxy ID="ram" runat="server">
    <AjaxSettings>
        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="btn_open_request_callback">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="btn_open_request_callback" UpdatePanelRenderMode="Inline"/>
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>      
    </AjaxSettings>
</telerik:RadAjaxManagerProxy>
```

Page2.ascx (Code Behind):

```cs
  protected void btn_open_request_callback_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            request_callback callback = new request_callback();
            callback.open_callback_model();            
        }
```

Page1.ascx (Code behind): - **Not calling Javascript function**

```cs
  public void open_callback_model()
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "open_callback_modal", "open_callback_modal();", true);
        }
```

Page1.ascx (JS function)

```
   function open_callback_modal() {
             alert('You clicked the button!')
             $get("btn_open_callback").click();
        }
```

Page1.ascx (Span click):

```
   <span id="btn_open_callback" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mdl_request_callback"></span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to register control:

```
<%@ Register Src="~/controls/request_callback.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="request_callback" %>   
<uc1:request_callback runat="server" id="request_callback" />
```